# Position of non-transparent div on a transparent div issue

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc-4

hi i am doing my project in mvc4 . in my Layout page i have a transparent div(#wrapper) and top of that i have many non transparent divs . I use the following css and html code for that.

```
<div id="wrapper">
<div id="header">
    <div id="logo"></div>
    <div id="navigation"></div>
</div>
 <div id="content">
    @RenderBody()
</div>
</div>
```

css

```
#wrapper {
position:relative;}

#wrapper:before {
margin-left:12%;
width:76%;
background-color:#6c88b6;
content:'';
min-height:400px;
height:auto;
overflow:hidden;
position:absolute;
opacity:.5;}

#header {
position:relative;
}

#logo {
margin-left:3%;
margin-top:20px;
margin-bottom:20px;
display:inline-block;
height:70px;
width:300px;
background:url(../Shared/Images/logo.png) no-repeat center left ;
}

#navigation {
margin-left:1%;
width:98%;
background-color:#fff;
height:50px;
}

#content {
  position:relative;
}
```

my problem is that the inside div's in wrapper(non transparent div's) position is not correct. They are not shows inside the wrapper div. How can i correct their position.

Comment: not clear which div is transparent and non-transparent.....

Comment: #wrapper is transparent . all others are non transparent

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with the :before pseudo-element?

Comment: @davidpauljunior: i am trying to achieve transparency not affecting other child div's and i got it

Comment: Oh you mean opacity.  I interpreted transparency as meaning invisible.

Comment: why do you use :before with #wrapper? Remove it! Also you can set color to wrapper with opacity: background: rgba(255,255,255,0.5)

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I found works. Use div's to set the height, width, padding, and other formatting options. Then a class element to set any colors, transparency, and other cosmetic. To make the classes transparent use

```
#class {
background-color:rgba(108.136.182.0.5)
}
```

that code should also work if you just place it into your "#wrapper" div as well. the first three decimals are the color and the last one is the opacity of the object. Also "1.0" or 1 is equal to 100%, that's why I used 0.5